# Matching characters in different languages

Tags: javascript, regex

Is this a right way to check for characters (both English and non English characters like umlauts in German and others)?

```
var alphabet = /[A-Za-z \u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]/g;
```

Comment: This regex does not accomplish the intended task of matching characters only. As a result, it is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Where comes the space?